# SELECT and COUNT with LEFTJOIN in mysql or Query Builder

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-5, count, left-join

I have table **`Company`**

```
+--------------------------+
| id |        companyname  |
+--------------------------+
| 1  |        JACK         |
| 2  |        ANDY         |
```

and table **`Job`**

```
+--------------------------------+
| id | id_com |    title job     |
+--------------------------------+
| 1  |    1   |     php          |
| 2  |    1   |     mysql        |    
| 3  |    1   |     html         | 
| 4  |    2   |     css          |
```

and I want my result like this :

```
id | company name |  Number of job |
+----------------------------------+
1  |  JACK        |      3         |
2  |  ANDY        |      1         |
```

- **Job** belong to **company**
- **Company** has many **job**

How can I do this with Mysql or Query Builder Laravel ?

Comment: This is a simple join and group by, what have you tried? I'm sure you're not the first one to ask about it

Comment: Thanks, this is my code using Query Builder Laravel 5.4 :  $result = company::leftjoin('jos', 'job.id', '=', 'company.id')->select('company.*', count('job.id'));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT c.id, c.companyname, count(j.id) AS NumberJobs
FROM Company c
LEFT JOIN Job j ON j.id_com = c.id
GROUP BY c.id, c.companyname
```

Comment: yes, I do like this but I'm not using GROUP BY before :(, thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

no more no less than :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fed682/9)

**Query 1**:

```
    SELECT c.id, c.companyname, count(j.id) AS nb 
    -- `sum(if(j.field IS NOT NULL, 1,0)) AS nb`
    -- may be used if you always have a join
    -- and want to check `j.field` instead
    FROM Company c
    LEFT JOIN Job j
        ON j.id_com = c.id
    GROUP BY c.id, c.companyname
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fed682/9/0)**:

```
| id | companyname | nb |
|----|-------------|----|
|  1 |        JACK |  3 |
|  2 |        ANDY |  1 |
|  3 |        VOID |  0 |
```

---

For Laravel, should look like :

```
$r = DB::table('Company')
    ->leftJoin('Job', 'Job.id_com', '=', 'Company.id')
    ->select(
        DB::raw('Company.id, Company.companyname, count(Job.id) AS nb'))
    ->groupBy(
        'Company.id', 
        'Company.companyname')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's working, and one more thing "how can I using this mysql for Query Builder Laravel 5.4

Comment: @HungNguyen I never used Laravel, give my 5 min, I take a look at the doc.

Comment: @HungNguyen try again, I've edited my answer just after the comment : forgot the `c` alias I used on the RAW sql query.

Comment: oh no, I'm really sorry, it's working fine, thank you so much